# Trying to get my IPv4 address gets VirtualBox's IPv4

Tags: vb.net, virtualbox, ipv4

I Tried Everything To Get My IPv4 Address ...

Some Examples:

```
Dim s As String = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(Function(a As IPAddress) Not a.IsIPv6LinkLocal AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6Multicast AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6SiteLocal).First().ToString()
```

_

```
Dim myClientMachineAddressList As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
Dim myClientMachineIP As String = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(0).ToString()
```

_

```
strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

_

```
Dim entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
    For Each address In entry.AddressList
        If address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            Return address.ToString
        End If
    Next
```

E.t.c.

... But All The Above Give Me VirtualBox's IPv4 Like:

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your computer has multiple IP address, as you already noticed.  Your code always returns the first one (order not guaranteed).  It just so happens that the first one is from the VirtualBox adapter.

Comment: Can I do something about that?

Comment: You can enumerate all the network adapters in the computer, looking for the one that meets your criteria (name, gateway, etc).  Then return the addresses from that adapter.  Sorry, I don't have the function names available right now.

Comment: Ok Thanks ..... :)

Comment: How can I get all the ips with their network adapter name?

Comment: This looks like it should be a good place to start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok I'll try it tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks @BradleyUffner for your help. I kinda solved my problem (See the answer i posted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I didn't find a way to get the ip I wanted, but i found a way to get all the available ips with their network adapter name. Here is the code in case anyone wants it:

First Import `System.Net.Sockets` , `System.Net` And `System.Net.NetworkInformation`

The code:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    For Each adapter As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
        lst.Add(adapter.Description & ": " & adapter.GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString)
    Next
```

`lst` is the list with all the network adapters and their ips

Comment: Nice work!  Just be aware that it is possible for a network adapter to have more than one address, but your code will only return the first one.  This may not be an issue for you though, if you code never runs on a computer with that kind of setup.  To fix it you would just do an inner loop over `adapter.GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses`.